# Blitz++ array in struct

Tags: c++, struct, blitz++

I would like to have a struct with several blitz++ arrays in it. this program creates such a struct, however I can't allocate the object properly. Is the only alternative to formulate a struct with *pointers* to a blitz++ array that is allocated outside of the struct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <blitz/array.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace blitz;

struct Bstruct{
    Array<double,1> B;
};

int main(){

    Bstruct str;
    Array<double,1> x(10);
    x = 1.0;
    str.B = x;

    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "str.B = " << str.B << endl;

    return 0;
}

➜  blitz_struct git:(master) ✗ ./struct
x = (0,9)
[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ] 

str.B = (0,-1)
[ ]
```

Comment: the end of the code snipped above shows you the output of the program. `x` and `str.B` should be the same.

Comment: presumably `blitz::Array` does not provide a proper/deep copy-assignment operator. and its apparent homepage is down, so I can't check the header!

Comment: yeah i know the homepage is down, this is really a pain. anyway, that works for now.

Answer (score 0):

i found this to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <blitz/array.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace blitz;

struct Bstruct{
    Array<double,1> B;
};

int main(){

    Bstruct str;
    Array<double,1> x(10);
    x = 1.0;
    str.B.resize(10);
    str.B = 1.0;

    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "str.B = " << str.B << endl;

    return 0;
}

➜  blitz_struct git:(master) ✗ ./struct                       
x = (0,9)
[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]

str.B = (0,9)
[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
```

Comment: right, so it seems like `blitz::Array` doesn't provide a non-broken copy-assignment operator. I'd be sure to avoid it, if I had any need for a non-Standard container. Is there a reason you can't use `std::vector`, which does have sane copy-assignment semantics?

Comment: yes, unfortunately this is a piece of legacy code written with blitz++ and changing that to anything else would be a huge amount of work. that's why.

Comment: oh sorry maybe i didn't your question. you are asking why i couldn't use a `std::vector` instead of the struct? I want to have a name for the element rather than `container.at(3)`, for example, as in `container.named_element`

Comment: @FlorianOswald I was meaning for the array itself. Ah well, good luck with the maintenance!

Comment: tell me about it! :-( thanks for listening in anyway!